# How to solve require error in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, require

I am trying to use require

```
require_once (__DIR__."./../config/config.php");
```

When I run this code, I got  No direct script access allowed.

How I should solve this?

Comment: you can create your library and load library when you need.

Comment: create library and put this code into that file then call library right?

Comment: yes right, and where you are trying to include the file which occure an error?

Comment: You do need to read the Documentation. It is why it was written... to be read.... https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html and https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html to start with. I am guessing your are writing your own library.